# APK which I developed used to work fine earlier, but suddenly stopped working with "App not installed" error

Tags: android, apk

I was working on an android app to push FCM notifications.
Now this debug app was getting installed on my mobile properly, however since am using my office laptop with intel-vt (HAXM) disabled I could not use the emulator and since the USB is also disabled, I could not use the ADB to side load.

So I was left with building the APK and manually side loading it on my mobile every time I made even a small change.(Redmi Note 5 Pro).

Now this app was working fine till the last time I uninstalled it.After which I tried to install the new version which failed with error "App not installed". Then I went on to install the older version thinking I might have screwed up something in the latest version, however all the older version APKs which were working absolutely fine earlier (at least they were installing i mean) stopped getting installed with the same error.

I have already uninstalled the older version and have double checked from system and there is no earlier APK existing on my mobile.

This is driving me crazy and has put a complete halt on my work as this is the only mobile I have. And yes I have tried restarting my mobile, I have even disabled MIUI optimizations from developers menu.

PS - I am an extreme noob at Android and have recently started with Android development so please forgive me if my question sounds very silly.

Appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: try deleting the apk file and rebuild it. Can you tell me if the aok is signed ?

Comment: Without providing any examples of exactly what you're doing you don't offer much for people trying to help you out. Try writing out sequential steps so that someone can replicate your problem and work through it with you or at least find an area to improve in your workflow.

Comment: @KaustubhKadam No this apk is not signed. I will delete the apk and generate a new one and try with that. However please note, when I installed this same APK on my friends mobile, it worked fine, so seems like some issue on my mobile, or some old cache files might still be present which is preventing it from getting reinstalled.

Comment: @domdambrogia Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JotinderSingh is the debug mode in your phone on ?

Comment: @domdambrogia Thanks for the advice.

Below are the steps which I had taken.

1) I have one MainActivity.java Activity which has one Show tkn btn, which displays FCM token in text field. 

2) This FCM token I am using in my python code on server using pyfcm to push notifications from my server to android app.

3) There are MyFirebaseMessagingService and MyFirebaseIstanceID classes which follow the most basic code, as given on the FCM website.

4) Earlier MainActivity.java ws the LAUNCHER activity, n the app icon on my mobile ws"FirebaseNotification" which ws correct.

Comment: 5) Later I made another activity with NavDrawer (hamburger menu) which was named MainActivity2. I edited the Android Manifest file to make this new activity as the LAUNCHER activity.

6) Post this change when I installed app, the app name was being shown as MainActivity2 instead of FirebaseNotifications. 

7) While installing this new updated APK, it said "MainActivity2 is part of FirebaseNotifications, are you sure you want to uninstall".

8) Even with this notification, it was fine, as I was able to install / uninstall and then again re-install multiple times without any issues.

Comment: Not sure if changing the default LAUNCHER activity had any impact.

Comment: @KaustubhKadam I can see USB debugging is enabled. There is another option which says "Select Debug App" however no debug application is set. Right now am not even able to install the app, so not wont be able to select the app under this option. Not sure if I am referring to the correct option.

Comment: @JotinderSingh Which phone is it ?

Comment: @KaustubhKadam Its a Redmi Note 5 Pro from Xiaomi.
I have disabled MIUI optimizations as well to ensure MIUI doesnt cause any problems.

Comment: @JotinderSingh I just googled a few things, and found following steps, couldnt check it myself as i do not have a Redmi phone   Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if it's listed.
Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check the Unknown Sources option.
Finally go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options: Check the Install via USB option.

Comment: @KaustubhKadam Thank you so much Kaustubh, the provided steps seemed to have worked. Everything was already the same,except the last step i.e. "Install via USB". Once I checked that option the APK installed properly.

Thank you so much for your help. 
And sorry if this was a really silly question to ask on this forum, as I sincerely respect this forum and it has got me out of trouble on numerous occasions.

Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: @JotinderSingh Please edit your question using the model of your phone, so that the others who are stuck in similar issue can resolve it. Thank you

Comment: @KaustubhKadam Thanks Bro. In fact I did mention the model name in my original post. Here it was :
* I was left with building the APK and manually side loading it on my mobile every time I made even a small change.(Redmi Note 5 Pro).

Comment: @jotindersingh you can also debug using wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the following steps:

- Go to Settings -> Permissions -> Install via USB: Uncheck your App if
  it's listed.
- Go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Privacy: Check the Unknown
  Sources option.
- Finally go to Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options:
  Check the Install via USB option.